# How to sort a list alphabetically using PHP- Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've created a shortcode that lists and links all my sites in my wordpress multi-site. It works fine, but the list is ordered by site ID by default. I need to mention that my site urls are differentiated by different domains and by path in my network. For example www.1.com/a, www.1.com/b, www.2.com/c, www.2.com, www.3.com are technically all network sites. My shortcode uses a built in WordPress function called get_sites(). Here's the codex page on it: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/

As you can see, there is a built in 'orderby' parameter for ID (default), domain, or path. But I can't order by site name. That's why I needed to use get_blog_details (see below) to pull out the site name. I ended up using jquery to alphabetize the list. Here's how I intended it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/tbalarajan/gbbrsy5k/

```
$("li").sort(function(a, b) {
var aText = $(a).text(), bText = $(b).text();
return aText < bText ? -1 : aText > bText ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('ul');
```

The problem is, the jquery only works because there's a static list to work with. When using my shortcode function along side my jquery, I get a list of ALL posts, profile pages, site urls, etc. It's ordered by alpha, but I don't want a list of 500+ links. I believe I need to sort this list only using PHP, but I'm not sure how. I took a look at sort() but that's dealing with an array and I'm unsure how to use it in this context.

Here's the function I'm using for my short code. Typing in [show_list] in the wysiwyg populates $html which is a list of about 30 sites.

```
function list_sites() {

$subsites = get_sites(); 

if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {

    $html = '<ol class="subsites">'; 

    foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {

        $subsite_id = $subsite->blog_id; //finds sites by id
        $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname; //creates variable for site name
        $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl; //creates variable for site url
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . $subsite_link . '">' . $subsite_name . '</a></li>'; //builds individual list items

    }

    $html .= '</ol>';

    return $html; //returns the list

}
```

}    add_shortcode('show_list', 'list_sites');

Any ideas or pointers in how to alphabetize the list using php would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you need to sort the links by site name. I think you can do this by utilizing PHP's associative array feature:

```
$sub_site_index = array();
$subsite_data = array();
foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {

    $subsite_id = $subsite->blog_id; //finds sites by id
    $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname; //creates variable for site name
    $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl; //creates variable for site url
    //$html .= '<li><a href="' . $subsite_link . '">' . $subsite_name . '</a></li>'; //builds individual list items
    $subsite_data[$site_name] = <li><a href="' . $subsite_link . '">' . $subsite_name . '</a></li>;
    $subsite_index[] = $site_name;
}
sort($subsite_index);
foreach($subsite_index as $item){
    $html .= $subsite_data[$item];
}
```